# why "#if !(protected) and !(private)" cannot defense "#define private public"?

Tags: c, macros

I try something to prevent someone force private to public like this:

```
#define private public
#if !(protected) and !(private)
#define A 1
#endif
class B{
private:
    int c;
};
int main(){
    int a=A;
    B b;
    b.c=2;
};
```

At start I think this code cannot compile because because

```
#define private public
```

will trigger

```
#if !(protected) and !(private)
```

to prevent A to define. But in fact this code can compile, but at the same time I can access the private member of B directly, that means private become public already. But why can A still define?

Comment: This should be tagged C++, not C.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never `#define` a keyword such as `private`. If you include any part of the standard library from the same `.cpp` file (even the parts needed for basic language features like `<new>` or `<initializer_list>`), the behavior is undefined.

That said, when `#if` evaluates its expression, any identifier or keyword token is treated as the number zero. The interpretation is as follows:

1. `#if !(protected) and !(private)`
2. `#if !(protected) and !(public)`
3. `#if !(0) and !(0)`
4. `#if true`

You're probably looking for the `defined` operator, which tells you whether its operand is a macro.

```
#if ! defined(protected) and ! defined(private)
```

Again, though, don't do this.

---

If your aim is to *prevent* someone from hacking keywords, it can be done like this:

```
#if defined(protected) || defined(private) || …
#   error Do not hack keywords!
#endif
```

This is going waay overboard with defensive coding. C++ doesn't really give you ammunition to prevent users from hacking your library. Users who don't follow the rules will hurt themselves before they hurt you… simply make it clear that oddball programs will not be supported. Even that should be unnecessary, and go without saying.

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
#if !(protected) and !(private)
```

is evaluated during the preprocessing phase.  During this phase, protected and private are treated as preprocessing tokens, not keywords.  private is replaced by public, since you've defined it as such.  Then the instances of protected and public are replaced by 0, since once all macro replacements are done, all remaining identifiers are always replaced by 0.  So the lines become

```
#if !(0) and !(0)
    #define A 1
#endif
```

The details of most of this can be found in 6.10.1 paragraph 4 of C99 and 16.1 paragraph 4 of C++11.

Answer (score 0):

The `private`, `protected`, and `public` sections are meant to prevent accidental abuse. They cannot be used to safeguard against intentional abuse.

It's trivial for a user to change

```
class B{
  private:
    int c;
};
```

to

```
class B{
  public:
    int c;
};
```

or to

```
class B{
  private:
    friend class UserClass;
    int c;
};
```

to gain access to private sections of `B`.

**Don't waste your energy on such things.**